# Image visualization does not work in Rviz [?]

Tags: ros, rviz, visualization, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I was trying to visualize a sensor_msgs/Image message using Rviz and had no success. Then, I found image_viewer plugin in rqt (rqt_image_viewer) and the image was always there. Is this an issue in Rviz? Do I have to report it as a bug? or Do these tools work in different ways?

P.D.: I'm using Hydro on Ubuntu 13.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127661/image-visualization-does-not-work-in-rviz-%5B?%5D/) by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 756 on 2014-02-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-09**:
I've seen this on OS X, and just assumed it was an OSX bug. Are you seeing it on Linux as well?

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2014-02-09**:
Yes @ahendrix, I'm running Hydro on Ubuntu 13.04

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-09**:
This sounds like an rviz bug, then. I'll open a ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm fairly convinced that this is a bug in rviz and I've opened a ticket about it: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/719

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2